# Is "Do you hear the people sing?"grammatically OK?

Tags: word-choice, tense

I'd always thought that they sing "Do you hear the people sing?" instead of "Do you hear the people's song?" in the main song of Les Miserables. Nevertheless, would it be grammatically OK, or should I rather use " Do you hear the people singing?"in this type of sentence?

Comment: You hear that because that's what the lyrics are... http://www.metrolyrics.com/do-you-hear-the-people-sing-lyrics-les-miserables.html where did you get the idea that the lyrics are "do you hear the people's song"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hear), **hear** can take an object followed by either an -ing verb or an infinitive without to, so it is grammatically correct.

My opinion is that we tend to use the -ing form when we hear something that goes on for a while, and the infinitive form for a single event:

> I heard him hit your car - *he did it once*
>   I heard him hitting your car - *he was doing it for a while*

With singing, one could reasonably expect it to go on for a while, so the -ing version is probably more appropriate:

> Do you hear the people singing?