# Could calling go here?

Tags: meaning

Do you know this song of the Velvet Underground "I heard her call my name"?

I was wondering why it is not calling instead of call because we can suppose that it happens many times not once, so calling seems to be a better way to express this idea. So could calling work here? What is the difference between the two?

I know it is a song and a writer may or may not respect grammar rules.

Comment: How do you know it didn't happen just once?

Comment: Verbs of perception like: hear, saw, feel etc. can take a gerund or a simple noun.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "Do you hear the people sing?"grammatically OK?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118294/is-do-you-hear-the-people-singgrammatically-ok)

Answer (score 1):

Either "call" or "calling" could be used if she called his name either once or multiple times. "Calling" is a present participle and thus connotes an ongoing activity, but "call" works for multiple instances of the activity, too.

An example:

> She called me all day, but I never responded.

Answer (score 0):

Verbs of perception like see, feel, hear and notice + a pronoun as a general rule, can take a noun or gerund:

- I heard her call my name. [She called my name once.]
- I heard her calling my name. [She called my name once or various times.]

The second, by using a gerund, **may imply it was more than once** at the same time: "Jean, Jean, oh Jean, where are you?" However, the first is only one.

Comment: ok but if he heard the girl calling her name once but every hour (I know it is a bit weird but we can imagine it ) is it better to use call or calling

Comment: @user5577 - neither is better. 'Call', having one syllable, fits the tune. 'Calling' would not.

Comment: @user5577 If you understood what I said, you wouldn't be asking this. :)